# Unable to connect with redis in app.get method

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to learn use case of `redis`. As each tutorial is suggesting that it is better for caching a data.

I have made a simple demo where I am trying to connect with `redis` server in a web service `get` method.

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // <== this is must

app.get('/fetch_offers', function (req, res) {
    client.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected');
    });
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(port)
})
```

I am trying to access it on localhost machine like http://localhost:8080/fetch_offers

I debugged it using `console.log` method but it does not print connected message. When I make this method outside the `app.get...` then it prints on executing `node app.js`.

I want it should make a `redis` connection on hitting a URL. I am not sure what is best way ? Can anyone help me ?

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; // <== this is must

client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');
});

app.get('/fetch_offers', function (req, res) {

});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(port)
})
```

What wrong I am doing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't print connection message because the event fires well before you hit the endpoint - at which point nothing is listening for it and it gets lost. Try something like this:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Redis connected');
});
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Redis ready');
});
client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Redis error:', err.message);
});
```

and then in your route handler you can use `ping` to see if you're connected:

```
app.get('/fetch_offers', function (req, res) {
  client.ping((err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Ping error:', err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Ping response:', data);
  });
});
```

It would be slightly easier if you use [promise-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-redis) and async/await:

```
app.get('/fetch_offers', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('Ping response:', await client.ping());
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Ping error:', err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I see that above program is trying to re-connect with redis server in case of connection lost. what method is doing that ?

Comment: @Williams The `redis` module does that automatically. See the docs: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#reconnecting

Comment: Ah, this is perfect